# Trouble centering and reducing the size of the ripple effect for material-ui RadioButton

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When reducing the size of the RadioButton in the Material-UI components for React, the ripple effect becomes off-center and too large. I cannot seem to find any style props to control it. Here is a working code.

```
const { MuiThemeProvider, getMuiTheme, RadioButtonGroup, RadioButton } = MaterialUI;

class RadioDemo extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <RadioButtonGroup
        name="orientation"
        style={{marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20, display: 'flex' }}
        required={true}
        validationError="This field is required."
      >
        <RadioButton value="1" label="button1" 
          style={styles.radioButton.style}
          labelStyle={styles.radioButton.label}
          iconStyle={styles.radioButton.icon}
          inputStyle={styles.radioButton.input}
        />

        <RadioButton value="2" label="button2"
          style={styles.radioButton.style}
          labelStyle={styles.radioButton.label}
          iconStyle={styles.radioButton.icon}
          inputStyle={styles.radioButton.input}
        />
      </RadioButtonGroup>
    );
  }

}

const styles = {
  radioButton: {
        style: {
            width: "140px"
        },
        label: {
            width: "100px",
            fontSize: "14px",
            padding: "0px",
            textAlign: "left"
        },
        icon: {
            heigh: "14px",
            width: "14px",
            padding: "0px",
            marginRight: "8px"
        },
        input: {
            width: "100px"
        }
   }
};




const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <RadioDemo />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

link to jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/brentjm/bppxsopw/7/

[animation-offcentered-radiobutton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JufP7.gif)

Additional details:
npm version 4.2.0

some package.json dependencies:

```
"react": "^15.2",
"react-dom": "^15.0.1",
"material-ui": "0.18.3",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0"
```

devDependencies

```
"webpack": "^1.13.1"
```

I'm not using react-toolbox.

Comment: can you provied a jsfiddle as example? Which npm do you use? react-toolbox?

Comment: Thank you for the response Felix. I've added the jsfiddle code and link, as wells as the npm version, and dependencies versions. I using material-ui, but not react-toolbox. Thanks for any help.

Comment: maybe have a look on this: https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/themes I thik your code is not correct

Comment: @Felix, thanks again for the look. The link you referenced is for material-ui version 1, and I'm still back on 0.18.3. I do use the <MuiThemeProvider /> for global styling in addition to the inline styles, but neither have helped address the ripple offset. Maybe the new styling approach in version 1 will help. Thank you again.